# Update Listview after deleting database item

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Ive been trying to get my listview to update after removing an item. Here's what I have so far:

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        String str = null;

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

            //TextView txtview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
            final String item = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtview)).getText().toString();
            str = item;
            final long arr = arg3;
            final String arg22 = longToString(arg3);

            //Creating an Alert Dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the hike " + str + " ?");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SQLiteDatabase db1=openOrCreateDatabase("hikeManager", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(Home.this);
                    String table = "hikes";

                    Cursor c = db1.rawQuery("select id from "+ table + " where  name='"+item+"'", null);
                    int dhike = c.getColumnIndex("name") + 1;

                    try {
                        Hike hike = db.getHike(arr + 1);
                        db.deleteHike(hike);
                        Log.d("DLT", "Deleted hike at index " + arr);
                        //db.updateList(adapter, myList, listItems);
                        adapter.remove(arg22);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //updateData();
                        db.close();
                    } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        Log.d("DLT", "Failed to delete: " + e.getMessage());
                        db.close();
                    }
                    //db.updateList(adapter, myList, listItems);



                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

I Have quite a bit of unused code in there, as I have tried a few different methods to get this to work, but have failed so far. Here is updateData:

```
private void updateData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtview, listItems);
    final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cardListView);

    int num = db.getHikesCount();
    for (int i=1; i<num+1; ++i){
        Hike name = db.getHike(i);
        String nam = name.getName();
        listItems.add(nam);
    }
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
}
```

The updateData does have some unintended consequences when I use it to update the view after adding an item to a non-empty list, but it works for now. The item is successfully deleted, since I can close the app and reload it and the item will be gone. I just cant seem to get it to update properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Try using this as a last line in onItemClick() One more thing, make your adapter as class variable i.e. declare it before onCreate(). Initialize it inside onCreate() so that you can use it anywhere in class.

Comment: Using it as a last line doesn't yield any changes.

Comment: You have to remove item at arg2 and not arg3. So try adapter.remove(arg2);

Comment: Same results as before. Maybe my implementation is messed up in some place, and is causing this issue. If it is any help, I have the code on Github (https://github.com/mvan4310/ElevationsApp).